# Sharepoint online run custom javascript after item added/edited

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to add an "item changed event" to a custom list. The idea would be to with JSOM copy that edited list item to another list.

Is their a way to do this from the listview web part? It would be fine to do this from The normal forms as well.

Comment: if only using javascript, you can build some custom forms, using REST API or CSOM to do the update then copy the data.
you can try CSR/JSLINK to implement the copy function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So in a custom form i use JSOM to update. I dont understand how to use JSLINK for the copying.
Have u any example to why I should use CSR for the copying part?

I guess I could from the form update the item and at the same time add the item to another list?

Comment: I guess if you add the item from a custom form with jsom, you can do stuff i the callback, for instance copy the item.

But I guess you cant handle when the user "quick edit" in the list?

Comment: that's correct, all the logic would triggered from the forms, so if it's datasheet view/quick edit, it won't work.
Other wise you should look at provider hosted add-in

Comment: Yeah, I guess remote event receivers would do the trick.
But as a solutions you could prevent the users from quick edit by turning it off.

Comment: another way is try using workflow instead of javascript, many things can be done over there.

Comment: Havent even thought of that. Make a wf in sp dedigner that gets started on itemedited. Works perfect on customlist item, since no checkout etc :)